# TypeError: Additional arguments should be named <dialectname>_<argument>, got 'autoload'

Tags: sqlalchemy, autoload

I have been running the exact same code for months, but today, this error occurred -

`TypeError: Additional arguments should be named <dialectname>_<argument>, got 'autoload'`

And this is the code -

```
connection = engine.connect()
metadata = db.MetaData()
segment_metrics_table = db.Table('analysis', metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
```

Thoroughly puzzled as to why it happened

Comment: `autoload` was removed in newer versions of sqlalchemy, you most probably updated and it stopped working

Comment: i can remove autoload from the code but then the mysql table doesn't get changed

Comment: You could downgrade SQL Alchemy to a version that still has autoload support. Or you could, according to the migration guide (https://docs.slalchemy.org/en/20/changelog/migration_20.html) update to use the autoload_with parameter.

Comment: Mark, here is the correct url: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/changelog/migration_20.html